# Scene background not displaying camera capture

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, 8thwall-xr

When I run my app on my Android device (Galaxy S8+, Nougat) I don't see the camera input as the scene background. I do see my 3D plane being applied to surfaces though.
I attached the XR Camera and XR Video Controllers to my main camera (unity default).
Running Unity 2017.2.0b9

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before. Try disabling Multithreaded Rendering. This can be found under Edit > Project Settings > Player.

[image]